# React / Redux: Header does not reload after log in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, axios

I'm having an issue with my ReactJS website, it doesn't refresh the header anymore after you log in. So it will still display "Login / Sign up" even though you're logged in, until you refresh the page.

I know what caused this to happen. I rewrote my Login page without using Redux (originally it used Redux). I would like to get rid of Redux.

**Old login function:**

```
export function loginUser(formValues, dispatch, props) {
  return axios
    .post(AuthUrls.LOGIN, formValues)
    .then((response) => {
      const token = response.data.key;
      dispatch(authLogin(token));
      localStorage.setItem("token", token);
      history.push("/");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      const processedError = processServerError(error.response.data);
      throw new SubmissionError(processedError);
    });
}
```

**New login function:**

```
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    event.preventDefault(); 

    axios
      .post(AuthUrls.LOGIN, form)
      .then((response) => {
        const token = response.data.key;
        localStorage.setItem("token", token);
        history.push("/");
        //TODO: Header doesn't reload after login
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("login error");
        console.log(error.response);
      });
  };
```

I'm not sure what part exactly is causing it to not reload anymore. If someone could steer me in the right direction that would be much appreciated. You can view my App and Header components below.

**App**

```
function App() {
  const [locale, setLocale] = useState("nl");
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <UserContext.Provider value={{ user: user, setUser: setUser }}>
        <LocaleContext.Provider value={locale}>
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Notifs />
            <Header setLocale={setLocale} user={user} setUser={setUser} />
            <MainContent />
          </ThemeProvider>
        </LocaleContext.Provider>
      </UserContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Header**

```
class Header extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    authenticated: PropTypes.bool,
    setLocale: PropTypes.func,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <HeaderContent
          authenticated={this.props.authenticated}
          setLocale={this.props.setLocale}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    authenticated: state.auth.authenticated, 
  };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Header);
```

**HeaderContent**

```
export default function HeaderContent(props) {
  const { authenticated, setLocale } = props;
  const { user, setUser } = React.useContext(UserContext);
  const classes = useStyles();

  useEffect(() => {
    loadUser();
  }, [authenticated, user]);

  const loadUser = () => {
    if (authenticated) {
      axios
        .get(AuthUrls.API_USER, {
          headers: {
            authorization: "Token " + getUserToken(),
          },
        })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log("Header: User logged in:");
          setUser(response.data);
          console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("Header: No user found.");
          console.log(error);
          console.log(error.response);
        });
    } else {
      setUser(null);
    }
  };

  const renderLinks = () => {
    if (authenticated) {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Typography>{user.email}</Typography>
          <Button color="inherit" href="./#/logout">
            <Translation translation={Translations.Log_out} />
          </Button>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Button color="inherit" href="./#/login">
            Login
          </Button>

          <Button color="inherit" href="./#/mollieform">
            Sign up
          </Button>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static" color="secondary">
        <Toolbar>
          {renderLinks()}
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Header component expects authenticated prop, but no where you are setting and passing it. if token is available then you should set authenticated value.

Comment: Possibly your issue is with `event.preventDefault()`, as event isn't currently passed into that function, it has no reference and is potentially breaking out of the function as an error?

Comment: @Ibz Without preventdefault, it will refresh the page before anything happened. It's definitely needed.

Comment: @Madhuri I still don't understand where it's grabbing authenticated from but I think there's some Redux magic going on here. It uses authenticated from rest-auth I think.

Comment: @SJ19 sorry, I wasn't clear with my explanation. I'm saying that you should add event as an argument to your function `const handleSubmit = event => {...}`